# AND \$CONDITIONS in sqoop import to be clarified, nothing imported, why?

Tags: import, sqoop

I am doing only `m=1`, meaning this is gonna to force the non-parallel importing, right?
My table has 500000 lines and I only want to import a portion using a where condition in a free query, here is my command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees --username root -P --query 'select emp_no, title from titles where "emp_no < 10020 AND \$CONDITIONS"' --target-dir /title_set --m 1;
```

When I check the result, it is showing empty but does have a _SUCCESS file:
[image: Directory listing with _SUCCESS file]
What's wrong with my import script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to write query with sqoop import , update your query as below.

1) Include query in single quotes.

`'select emp_no, title from titles where emp_no < 10020 AND $CONDITIONS`'

2) Include query in double quotes.

```
"select emp_no, title from titles where emp_no < 10020 AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

The below is from Sqoop documentation about this.

If you are issuing the query wrapped with double quotes ("), you will have to use \$CONDITIONS instead of just $CONDITIONS to disallow your shell from treating it as a shell variable. For example, a double quoted query may look like: "SELECT * FROM x WHERE a='foo' AND \$CONDITIONS"

Comment: Thank you, that works! it's weird someone in my another question told me to include the quote on the where clause.